# Arduino read string from serial line and compare

Tags: arduino, serial-port, string-comparison

I'm trying to read a string from the serial line and compare it to a list of commands. If the string is a valid command the Arduino should go ahead and do something, and return some info on the serial line. 
However, my comaprison always fails (give me the "not a valid command response"). I have tried sending the word "temp" both from the Arduino serial monitor and from a Python script.

My arduino code:

```
int sensorPin = 0; // Sensor connected to A0
int ledPin = 13; // Led connected to 13
int reading = 0; // Value read from A0

float voltage = 0; // Voltage we read
float temperatureC = 0; // Temperature we measure

String inputString= ""; // Set string empty
String Temperature = "temp"; // The command we are looking for

boolean stringComplete = false; // See if we are done reading from serial line



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  inputString.reserve(200); // Reserve space for inputString in memory
}

void serialEvent() {
  // Read data from serial line until we get a \n.
  // Store data in inputString
  while (Serial.available()){
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inputString += inChar;
    if (inChar == '\n'){
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  serialEvent(); // See if there are data on serial line and get it
  if (stringComplete){ // If we are done reading on serial line
    if (inputString == Temperature){ //WHY YOU FAIL ME?
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      voltage = (analogRead(sensorPin) * 5.0)/1024.0;
      temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
      Serial.print(voltage); Serial.println(" volts");
      Serial.print(temperatureC); Serial.println(" degrees C");
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("Not a valid command:");
    Serial.print(' '+inputString);
  }
  // Reset so we can wait for a new command
  inputString = "";
  stringComplete = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd avoid using the `String` object. It's better, in my opinion, to just use char arrays. They are lighter and avoid memory allocation and deallocation.

By the way, why are you reserving the space if, later, you are assigning it a new  empty string?

Anyway, I think that the problem is that you are appending also the new line to the string. Moreover, in a windows environment a new line is a `'\r'` followed by a `'\n'`, so you get different behaviour in Win and Linux.

I'd just replace

```
inputString += inChar;
if (inChar == '\n'){
  stringComplete = true;
}
```

with

```
if ((inChar == '\r') || (inChar == '\n')){
  stringComplete = (inputString.length() > 0);
} else {
  inputString += inChar;
}
```

EDIT: I'd also add a break in the stringComplete case, since otherwise multple commands can't be detected. So:

```
if ((inChar == '\r') || (inChar == '\n')){
  if(inputString.length() > 0) {
    stringComplete = true;
    break;
  }
} else {
  inputString += inChar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
inputString += inChar.trim();
```

Instead of.

```
inputString += inChar;
```